# "OperationalError, unrecognized token" while searching

Tags: django, search, full-text-search, django-queryset

I'm getting this error while making any search query:

```
OperationalError at /search/
unrecognized token: "@"
```

My view:

```
class Search(ListView):

    model = Opinion
    template_name = 'home/search.html'
    context_object_name = 'search_results'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Opinion.objects.all()

        keywords = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if keywords:
            query = SearchQuery(keywords)
            vector = SearchVector('text')
            qs = qs.annotate(search=vector).filter(search=query)
            qs = qs.annotate(rank=SearchRank(vector, query)).order_by('-rank')

        return qs
```

My search form:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="get" action="{% url 'home:search' %}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" value="">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

Any suggestion or feedback will be welcomed and greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you're using a PostgreSQL database.

I ran into this error when I tried to search my local database, which was SQLite.

Comment: Although it's short, it may be an answer.